# UnicodeDecodeError в Flask

Tags: python, flask, utf-8, unicode, django

Имеется проект на Flask 0.9. Интерпретатор версии 2.7.3.
Проблема такая. В проекте, в папке static лежит boostrap.
Я пытаюсь подгрузить стиль оттуда не получается :(
Шаблон грузиться, смотрю код которые рендирит браузер. Он не подгружает bootstrap.css если я пытаюсь открыть через код в браузере. То вылезаете
**UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)**

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__
  return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
  response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
  response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1360, in               full_dispatch_request
 rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1358, in     full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1344, in   dispatch_request
  return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 867, in   send_static_file
  cache_timeout=cache_timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 657, in send_from_directory
  filename = safe_join(directory, filename)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 627, in safe_join
  return os.path.join(directory, filename)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 80, in join
  path += '/' + b
```

Вот сам код

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Buraevo Info</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta name="description" content="">
   <meta name="author" content="">

 <!--Если кликнуть, то подхватите ошибку -->
 <link href="static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <style type="text/css">
  body {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
  }
```

Я что то не могу понять. в чем тут проблема с Юникодом. Файлы сохранены в UTF-8. В каждом файле написан # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- кроме шаблонов конечно.

Comment: операционка какая?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10 x86

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего сам файл *bootstrap.css* сохранён не в юникоде. Просто пересохрани его любым текстовым редактором в юникодной кодировке.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй скачай Bootstrap и замени его в static.